# How to send only 1 parameter with get method?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I have a controller with this index method
(app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb)

```
...
  before_action :find_user, only: [:show, :destroy]

  def index
    @users = User.order('created_at DESC')
  end
...
```

And I have a view 
(app/view/api/v1/users/index.json.jbuilder)

```
json.array! @users do |user|
  json.id user.id
  json.name user.name
  json.posts user.posts do |post|
    json.id post.id
    json.title post.title
    json.body post.body
  end
end
```

And when I run the server it works fine, after accessing `localhost:3000/api/v1/users` it is showing the expected output.
But when I launch these RSpec tests 
(spec/controllers/api/v1/users_controller_spec.rb)

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::UsersController, type: :controller do
  describe "GET #index" do
    before do
      get :index
    end
    it "returns http success" do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end
end
```

I get an error [image]
If I remove `:index` from `get :index` it gives the same error but (given 0, expected 1).
How come `get :index` sending 2 parameters if there is only one and how can I rewrite this code so the test will pass?

If I rewrite index method like this

```
  def index
    @users = User.order('created_at DESC')
    render json: @users, status: 200 
  end
```

The test will pass, but in this case I will not get the JSON file that I need (which I made with jbuilder)

Comment: Have you tried doing the GET by hand with `curl` so that you can get a better stack trace? The error (an `ActionView::Template::Error`) and the work-around (don't use the template) suggest that your problem is in the jbuilder template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution some time ago. All I had to do is to place

```
  gem 'rspec-core', git: 'https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core'
  gem 'rspec-expectations', git: 'https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations'
  gem 'rspec-mocks', git: 'https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks'
  gem 'rspec-rails', git: 'https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails'
  gem 'rspec-support', git: 'https://github.com/rspec/rspec-support'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
```

in my Gemfile.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the `get` request under your `it` block

try

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::UsersController, type: :controller do
  describe "GET #index" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end
end
```

[RSpec documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/controller-spec)